# Salesforce Apex Class 99 %. Is there any way I can extract the classes which are not being run or not used any Internal or external system

Tags: apex, tooling

In our Organization Apex class has reached 99%. I have tried tooling API to fetch meta data and try to see unused methods and code as suggested in some of the articles but couldn't find any good one. Can anyone please let me know what the best ways are to find out. I am also scanning all installed manage package to see if any unused apex class.

Thanks
Jody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the CTO of Metazoa and we build a suite of tools that can detect and remove unused Apex Classes, unused Methods, and duplicate Methods. Here is a white paper on how it works:

https://www.metazoa.com/best-practices-apex-class-and-method-management/

Comment: thank you. Is there any way we can try the trial version of same.

Comment: Hi David, absolutely, get it on the AppExchange and start a 14 day free trial with training